# How to enable HTTP Proxy for Office add-ins

Tags: office-js

I'm trying to setup a Word add-in (on both Windows and MacOS) and was wondering if there was any mechanism to have the HTTP requests routed through a proxy?
I don't want to set an http proxy for the entire machine but instead just for the Word process or even better just for the add-in itself.
Does any proxy setting or other mechanism to set that exist?

Comment: You're referring to the HTTP requests that you initiate right? Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: I'm referring to the URLs specified in the extension OfficeApp xml file.  Like the FunctionFile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/functionfile) or the SourceLocation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/sourcelocation).

Comment: I'd appreciate the green tick if it qualifies as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the question, the developer is looking for a way to proxy the requests which are initiated by the Office Client and not through the already-loaded JavaScript.

**There's no default way of doing this unfortunately**. Also - Word uses IE in Windows, an iFrame in online and some browser type in MacOS to display the add-in which means you need to catch the requests not through the Word but through the other application type (again IE for Windows). As a simple exercise, start up your Office.js add-in and open the process viewer. You should see IE with your add-in reference.